# Check Adjacency in Triangle Array

Tags: java, algorithm, multidimensional-array, artificial-intelligence

For a school project i had to code the cracker barrel triangle peg game, http://www.joenord.com/puzzles/peggame/3_mid_game.jpg heres a link to what it is. I made a triangle symmetric matrix to represent the board

```
|\
|0\
|12\
|345\
|6789\.... 

public int get( int row, int col ) 
    {
        if (row >= col) // prevents array out of bounds 
            return matrix[row][col];
        else
            return matrix[col][row];
    }       //
```

and here is my `get()` function that's the form of the matrix. if i try to access `get(Row, Column)` and `row>column` i access `get(column, row)` its set that way in all my methods. This way its easier to prevent out of bounds stuff from happening. empty spots in the triangle are set to 0, all pegs are set to 1. There's unrelated reason why i didn't use a `Boolean` array. The project is a AI project and to develop a heuristic search algorithm i need access to the number of pegs adjacent to each other. I can easily prevent most duplicates by simply dividing by total/2 since it will count every adjacent in both directions. I don't know how to prevent duplicate checks when i cross that middle line. It only matters on the 0 2 5 and 9 positions. If i really wanted to i could write a separate set of rules for those positions, but that doesn't feel like good coding and is not functional for different sized triangles. any input is welcome and if you need more information feel free to ask.

Comment: 0 2 5 9..... this sounds like an arithmetic progression; so maybe you can think a function which can give you the value for the i-th element

Comment: i dont access get(5th index) i have to do get(2,2), and i just answered my own question thanks to you. Whenever a=b invoke the separate rules.

Answer (score 0):

0, 2, 5, 9 is not an arithmetic progression. The finite differences 2-0 = 2, 5-2 = 3, 9 - 5 = 4 are in arithmetic progression. So the sequence is 0, 0 + 2 = 2, 2 + 3 = 5, 5 + 4 = 9, 9 + 5 = 14, 14 + 6 = 20, etc. They are one less than the triangle numbers 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, etc. The nth triangle number has a short-cut expression, n(n+1)/2 (where n starts at 1, not 0). So your numbers are n(n+1)/2 - 1 for n = 1, 2, 3, ...

Anyway, the situation you are experiencing should tell you that setting it up so get(row,col) == get(col,row) is a bad idea. What I would do instead is to set it up so that your puzzle starts at index 1,1 and increases from there; then put special values -1 in the matrix entries 0,y and x,0 and anything with col > row. You can check for out of bounds conditions just by checking for the value -1 in a cell. Then to count the number of pegs surrounding a position you always do the same thing: check all four adjacent cells for 1's.